# Increasing the height of textarea when load data from database based on content in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, textarea, autosize

Actually I want to load some data into the Textarea field from a database but sometimes there is 1,2 or 3 lines text coming from the database. So how can I handle the size of Textarea dynamically in AngularJS? I read some questions and answer but there were about ng-keyup that working when I take input from the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

To set rows and columns dynamically, use interpolation:

```
<textarea ng-model="text" rows="{{rows}}" cols="{{columns}}">
</texteare>
```

And set them in the controller:

```
$scope.rows = 3;  //or 1 or 2
$scope.columns = 25;

$scope.text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempo"
```

Comment: Actually I want when there is 1 line of text then the number of rows 1 and 2 lines of text then number of rows 2. I have put this textarea data inside a table.